# Establishing a particular inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

Let $m_t(\xi) = \exp(2\pi i t \xi)$. I want to show that $m_t(\xi)$ is not a Hormander symbol, where we define a Hormander symbol to be a smooth function away from the origin such that, for all multi-indices $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^d$, there exists a constant $C_{\alpha}$ such that for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^d$, we have $$\left| m_t(\xi) \right| < C_{\alpha} \left| \xi \right|^{-\left| \alpha \right|}.$$

Is the following approach legitimate? \begin{eqnarray*}
\left| \partial^{\alpha} m_t(\xi) \right| = \left| (2\pi i t)^{\alpha} m_t(\xi) \right| &=& \left| (2\pi i t)^{\alpha} \exp(2\pi i t \xi) \right| \\
& > & \left| (2\pi i t)^{\alpha} \right| \cdot \left| 2\pi i t \xi \right|  \\
&=& \left| (2\pi i t)^{\alpha +1}\right|  \left| \xi \right|, 
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Just use that for real arguments $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $|e^{ix}| = 1$.

Your estimate is not correct, for instance $|e^{2\pi i}| = 1 < 2\pi = |2\pi i|$.